# Override Search module's textfield CSS ID

Tags: theming, search, forms

this is what I am using to override the Search module's submit button's CSS ID:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['id'][] = 'custom_css_id';
    }
}
```

Now I want same thing for the textfield input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same thing as you did above

```
$form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['id'][] = 'custom_css_id';
```

Comment: I always wondered why they called that input 'search_block_form', it's very confusing

Comment: @Clive the other day the same question came to my mind as well. Why would they give the input field the same name as the form id or the block name. :)

Comment: Wooow thanks for fast reply. I gotta bookmark this website. Yes I knew it had to be same thing but since I am just a designer this all drupal theming is really hard for me. It worked, thanks a lot. But now do you know how do I disable that element.style the input gets? It overrides my color. I cannot edit CSS, I know I could set !important.

Comment: @user13176 I would suggest you should have a look at the devel module http://drupal.org/project/devel and its docs. It will help you in the future to debug stuff like this one.